# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException When press Back

Tags: java, android, runnable, audio-player, android-music-player

I have Runnable that runs in Thread in a MediaPlayer. When i press back  I get an IllegalStateException.

Here is the Runnable:

mp is MediaPlayer

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() //This line is AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:318
       {

           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };
```

OnDetroy method:

```
@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
 }
```

Error log:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
        at com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity$9.run(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:318)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is there any method which gets invoked when you hit back button?

Comment: Please post your on pause on stop ondestroy n on back press code ..think some check need to added there

Comment: Please POST the complete error log.

Comment: Please check MediaPlayer STATE. getDuration function is valid on prepared state. Check [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you called `mp.pause()` in `OnPause()` method of this activity. So when you clicked back button, MediaPayer went into pause status. However since your Runnable is called asynchronous, so it will call mp.getDuration() in an invalid state. To fix this, please add in the check:

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
   long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
   long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
}
```